# Scrapy on a schedule

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, twisted

Getting Scrapy to run on a schedule is driving me around the Twist(ed).

I thought the below test code would work, but I get a `twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable` error when the spider is triggered a second time:

```
from quotesbot.spiders.quotes import QuotesSpider
import schedule
import time
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

def run_spider_script():
    process.crawl(QuotesSpider)
    process.start()


process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
})


schedule.every(5).seconds.do(run_spider_script)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I'm going to guess that as part of the CrawlerProcess, the Twisted Reactor is called to start again, when that's not required and so the program crashes. Is there any way I can control this?

Also at this stage if there's an alternative way to automate a Scrapy spider to run on a schedule, I'm all ears. I tried `scrapy.cmdline.execute` , but couldn't get that to loop either:

```
from quotesbot.spiders.quotes import QuotesSpider
from scrapy import cmdline
import schedule
import time
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


def run_spider_cmd():
    print("Running spider")
    cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl quotes".split())


process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
})


schedule.every(5).seconds.do(run_spider_cmd)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**EDIT**

Adding code, which uses Twisted `task.LoopingCall()` to run a test spider every few seconds. Am I going about this completely the wrong way to schedule a spider that runs at the same time each day?

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import task
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):

        quotes = response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]')

        for quote in quotes:

            author = quote.xpath('.//small[@class="author"]/text()').extract_first()
            text = quote.xpath('.//span[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first()

            print(author, text)


def run_crawl():

    runner = CrawlerRunner()
    runner.crawl(QuotesSpider)


l = task.LoopingCall(run_crawl)
l.start(3)

reactor.run()
```

Comment: Why not simply use cron or systemd timers?

Comment: The web-scraping of data is only one part of the intended application, and I am hoping to have everything run as part of a single program. But yes, if I can't get this working as described, I will use an OS task scheduler to run the Scrapy script, with the rest of application running separately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First noteworthy statement, there's usually only *one* Twisted reactor running and it's not restartable (as you've discovered). The second is that blocking tasks/functions should be avoided (ie. `time.sleep(n)`) and should be replaced with async alternatives (ex. 'reactor.task.deferLater(n,...)`).

To use Scrapy effectively from a Twisted project requires the [`scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner) core API as opposed to `scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess`. The main difference between the two is that `CrawlerProcess` runs Twisted's `reactor` for you (thus making it difficult to restart the reactor), where as `CrawlerRunner` relies on the developer to start the reactor. Here's what your code could look like with `CrawlerRunner`:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from quotesbot.spiders.quotes import QuotesSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner

def run_crawl():
    """
    Run a spider within Twisted. Once it completes,
    wait 5 seconds and run another spider.
    """
    runner = CrawlerRunner({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
        })
    deferred = runner.crawl(QuotesSpider)
    # you can use reactor.callLater or task.deferLater to schedule a function
    deferred.addCallback(reactor.callLater, 5, run_crawl)
    return deferred

run_crawl()
reactor.run()   # you have to run the reactor yourself
```

Comment: Thanks @notorious.no , this has begun clearing things up for me, but unfortunately I couldn't get this working on a schedule. I'm probably missing something obvious, but I don't see how I would implement this to run a spider at a specific time each day? The closest I can get is using Twisted `task.LoopingCall()`, which I could use to run a spider every 86400 seconds for a daily scrape, but am I going about this the wrong way? I've updated my post with the code for the loop, would really appreciate your guidance!

Comment: LoopingCall will work fine and is the simplest solution. You could also modify the example code (ie. `addCallback(reactor.callLater, 5, run_crawl)`) and replace `5` with the number of seconds that represents when you want to scrape next. This will give you a bit more precision as opposed to `LoopingCall`

Comment: Thanks @notorious.no . I misunderstood what was happening with the `deferred.addCallback`, a bit of timestamping in debug and it's starting to make sense. This is finally going to work for me, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @notorious.no I have a problem. Could you please help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74072040/try-except-and-schedule-for-scrapy Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can use apscheduler

```
pip install apscheduler
```

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from apscheduler.schedulers.twisted import TwistedScheduler

from Demo.spiders.baidu import YourSpider

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
scheduler = TwistedScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(process.crawl, 'interval', args=[YourSpider], seconds=10)
scheduler.start()
process.start(False)
```

Comment: This will not work with Django: the spider will open but not scrape or block the server's initialization.