# i have python script in spyder and i want it to run daily at 4pm

Tags: python, spyder

I have python script saved as `blocking_oth` in spyder and I want to automatically run this script every day at 4 p.m.

I have tried this -

```
import schedule
import time
import os

def job():
    os.system('Blocking_oth')


schedule.every().day.at("16:05").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

But this is giving me error :

> "NameError: name 'Blocking_oth' is not defined"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy on a schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44228851/scrapy-on-a-schedule)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do

```
os.startfile(path[, operation])
```

os.system is for running cmd commands.