# Scrapy spider - Scheduling process like rq worker

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I need to schedule the scrapy spiders in different time zones. Previously I have used the rq worker for the python script it dosen't support the scrapy spider.

Kindly anyone can suggest the idea to schedule the scrapy spiders

Answer (score 1):

[TwistedScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/schedulers/twisted.html) from [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) can handle scheduling of Scrapy and also supports time zones.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59016904/9003106) is an example that uses APScheduler to schedule Scrapy-spiders. You would have to edit the call of the `add_job()`-method to fit your specific needs, so add the `timezone`-parameter to it, change the trigger from `interval` to `date` or `cron` etc. See [APSchedulers official documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_job) for all available parameters.